# Google Cardboard XR Settings

Tags: virtual-reality, google-cardboard

Is there a way to access settings for Google XR Cardboard? I've got a project straight from Google Cardboard for Unity with examples. After building it and running on a phone it shows X and Gear icons in corners of the screen. X exits the application, Gear shows some settings. Can I modify these settings?

Loading up the package creates XR Settings scriptable object, which has nothing in it. I think maybe I should extend the class, fill it with custom settings (by some key that will be then recognized by Google XR) and replace instance of generic XR Settings with my custom ones?

Comment: Can you clarify what specific setting you want to access / add?

Comment: For example a login form. So that user can login by tapping (and has easier time with email confirmation) instead of by using VR keyboard within VR experience.